# How a session variable in php multi domain?

Tags: php, session

I have a dedicated server with 3 website on:

www /

www / site1 (www.site1.com)

www / site2 (www.site2.com)

www / site3 (www.site3.com)

I am that if a session is created either on site1, site2 website or 3 it is made available to the other two, for example in the context of authentication.

Site1: => Member 1  => Log ok, create the session id

```
<?php 
$ _SESSION ['Id'] = $user-> id; 
echo $ _SESSION ['id']; // Returns 1 
?>
```

I need regular.>

And as on site2 and website 3.

Comment: Are the sites accessed via a common domain. As in foo.com/site1 foo.com/site2 or site1.com / site2.com or site1.foo.com site2.foo.com ?

Comment: No they are accessble via separate domain name, site.com, site2.com..t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution at once! 
I check on the index of the site if user_id session exists, whether it is connected so it's ok if it does not exist so I made ​​a redirect to the main site. 
If the session is I go through this url key user and connect the member with respect to this key (encrypt). But if it has not been found I did just a redirect to the site desired by the user! :) 
Easy as pie (French term ^^) and functional! 
thank you for your answer!

If you want to ask me the code.

Answer (score 4):

There are two things that need to match between sites for the same session to be accessible from both:

1. How and where the sessions are stored.
2. The Session ID that identifies that particular session.

For (1), if you are using the standard file-based session storage, you simply need to point all the sites at the same directory on disk for storing the sessions, by setting [the `session.save_path` setting](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) to the same value.

For (2), you need to pass the output of [`session_id()`](http://php.net/session_id) on one site and set it using that same function on the next. The easiest way to do this is by creating a link with the session ID on the query string, e.g. `'http://site2.example.com/?passed_session_id=' . session_id()`

However, **beware of the security implications**. There are two different types of attack this makes your application vulnerable to:

- *Session hijacking*: anyone who can intercept that query string can go to that URL and claim the session as their own, thus becoming the user whose session that was.
- *Session fixation*: more subtly, if an attacker can trick a user to going to a URL with a fake session ID on the query string, they can choose the user's session ID in advance. Again, they can then become that user by setting a cookie with the known session ID.

You can defend against such attacks with a few counter-measures:

- Only pass the session ID on the query string in specific circumstances. If possible, do it only on secure pages, to minimise the chance of the URL being intercepted. However, it will still show up in browser history, for instance.
- Change the session ID using [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) whenever the user logs in or out, or otherwise changes privilege level. This reduces the scope of fixation attacks because the attacker's session will become invalid once the user logs in.
- If possible, change the session ID every time you hand off to a different site (i.e. every time the session ID is read off the query string). This has the downside of limiting the session to moving from site to site, or copying at a particular moment, rather than being truly shared.
- Include a "nonce" with the session when passing over. This is a string which you save to the session and pass on the query string, and then delete after use, or if it becomes too old. For instance `$_SESSION['session_passing'] = array('nonce' => uniqid(), 'time_limit' => strtotime('+2 minutes')); $url = 'http://site2.example.com/?passed_session_id=' . session_id() . '&nonce=' . $_SESSION['session_passing']['nonce'];` If, when reading a session ID from the query string, the nonce doesn't match what is in the session, or the time limit has passed, do not allow access to that session (just create a new empty session as though the user hadn't visited the site before.) When the nonce *does* match, delete it from the session, so that loading that same URL no longer works.
- Store additional identifying information, such as the remote IP and user agent, in the session when it first starts, and check that it matches on all subsequent page loads. This means the attacker must know more than just the session ID to take over the session.

A completely robust implementation is tricky, but some combination of the above counter-measures should make you less of an easy target.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can send the session id via some PHPSESSID query string to site n°2 in ajax, but I don't know if it will do the job ...

2) If user goes to website#2, consider pushing that session_id via some ajax or through query string, your php will unserializes that session_id on /tmp/session_id

then creates a new session if system won't handle same session_id on two distinctive hosts, also store the base session_id into that new session if you wanna handle new information that will be later stored via website#1 to unserialize it over and over ..

Comment: I will later try with Ajax but I'm tank .. 
Otherwise can for cookies, whether the member and connected to a site I can can do:

setcookie("Logged","HashID",time()+3600,"/",".site1.com");

setcookie("Logged","HashID",time()+3600,"/",".site2.com");

setcookie("Logged","HashID",time()+3600,"/",".site3.com");

Comment: @demenvil You can't set cookies for domains other than the one you are on (the browser will simply reject them for security reasons), so you still need a way of passing the value between domains in order to set those cookies.